# Mule 3.6.1 MMC shows ESB with red circle

Tags: mule

I have a Mule 3.6.1 ESB server up and running and a MMC server to manage it. The problem I'm seeing is every time I need to restart the ESB server manually (to fix something) the MMC shows the server with an error (red circle) even when the ESB is back up and running normally (APIs are responding without issues).

Any idea how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue may occur for various reasons, the console polls the managed instances every certain period so you need to at least wait for that period of time to see this, also if you have something in between the console and the managed instance such as a proxy it might be caching the responses, finally I would check if it is a display issue, by trying to reload the page.